# Iterating over sequence in a 1000 nucleotide window

Tags: python, file-io, file-writing

I am trying to write in Python a code to go over each sequence in my fasta file and print a new list of each sequence using a 1000 nucleotide sliding window, but I am not sure what is wrong.

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object"
```

Here is my code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta.txt", "fasta"):
    pos=0
    if pos<len(record)+1:
        dna_1000.write("\n"+">"+record.id+"_"+pos+"\n"+record[pos:pos+1000])
        pos=pos+1000
```

I tried it slightly differently:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta.txt", "fasta"):    
    for pos in range(0,len(record)+1,1000):
        dna_1000.write("\n"+">"+record.id+"_"+"\n"+record[pos:pos+1000])
```

but I also receive this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

Many thanks for taking a look at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code fails with `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` because of the line `dna_1000.write(...+'_'+pos+...)`
 where you add the object `'_'` where `type('_') = str` to the object `pos` where `type(pos) = int`. This is impossible because Python never implicitly adds strings  and ints: you have to turn the int into a string before adding it: `dna_1000.write(...+'_'+str(pos)+...)`.

Now we encounter your other error `TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object`. This originates from the `dna_1000.write` method which complains that it doesn't know what to do with its argument. It expects something like a string but gets `"\n"+">"+record.id+"_"+str(pos)+"\n"+record[pos:pos+1000])` which is a SeqRecord. This is because `record` is a SeqRecord, slicing a SeqRecord gives you a SeqRecord, and adding a string to a SeqRecord gives you a SeqRecord (with a modified nucleotide sequence).

To actually access the sliced `record`'s underlying nucleotide sequence you need to use `.seq`, and to write it to a file you need to convert it to a string. So to make your code run without errors you could do something like:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta.txt", "fasta"):
    pos=0
    if pos<len(record)+1:
        seqstr = str(record[pos:pos+1000].seq)
        dna_1000.write("\n"+">"+record.id+"_"+str(pos)+"\n"+seqstr)
        pos=pos+1000
```

Whether this is the best way to solve your problem (or whether this code even does what you expect) is another question that I don't have the background to answer. My only other suggestion is to read through http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO to see if any of the included IO functions would help.

Comment: Thank you Trevor for the explanation. I understand that Python can't combine strings and integers but I have a hard time applying this rule when I write the code.

Your suggestion was indeed helpful. I only needed to change the "if" loop to a "while" loop because otherwise it was only showing the 'first' sliding window for all the records because the if statement was true (pos was defined outside). It works now beautifully. Many thanks again!